# ManyToManyField Issue

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-1.6

Can someone please help me with this ManyToManyField issue

MODELS.PY

```
class Course(models.Model):
    course_code = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True)
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_code


class Degree(models.Model):
    degree_code = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
    degree_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.degree_code
```

Now when I query

```
>>> Degree.objects.values_list('courses')
[(4,), (3,), (1,), (5,), (4,), (3,), (2,), (1,)]
```

I am getting IDs, how can I get the course name instead of ID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do this by accessing the fields of the related class thus:

`Degree.objects.values_list('courses__course_name')`

Documentation for [Field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) explains it.